# How to receive in-app notifications which canceled/refunded purchases

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've used `'getPurchases' API call` to check the **state** ,but always return *null*

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Always post some code along with your question. so that we can figure it out why its returning null!!

Comment: `Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),itemType, continueToken);`

Comment: the first param '3' was a global variable which form Billing response codes

Comment: I have use all the Billing response codes ,such as 0 , 1 , 3 , 4 ,7 , but always return null

Comment: `// Billing response codes
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK = 0;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED = 1;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR = 6;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8;`

Comment: 3 from  getPurchases is InAPP Billing library Version code. not the above codes.